# Why I can't push this commit on my GIT repository? error: failed to push some refs to my_repo

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-push

I am finding the following problem pushing on my GIT (BitBucket) repository.

If I do **git push** I obtain the following error message:

```
$ git push
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

So I tried to do **git push origin master** but give me the following error message:

```
$ git push origin master
To https://bitbucket.org/AndreaNobiliProjects/glis-trigger.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://AndreaNobiliProjects@bitbucket.org/AndreaNobiliProjects/glis-trigger.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What could be the problem? How can I try to fix it?

I explain what I have done before obtain this error message:

- I tried to push but I can't because on the repository there was some changes made by another person.
- I pull from the repository but I don't want use these changes so I replaced the content of my project with my version (I had done a backup before the pull).
- I commit and pushed again and I am obtaining this error.

What can I do to solve this situation?

Answer (score 2):

`! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)`

The push is rejected by a hook in the remote repository because it's not a fast-forward push. The local master and the remote master are diverged.

Reset the local master to the backup revision and then run `git pull --rebase origin master`. The new local commits will be rebased onto the remote master's tip. After rebase, the push will be a fast-forward one.

Comment: Ok...I want to understand...what is a "fast-forward push"? and what have I to do exactly? From what I have understood I have to take my backup (my version of the code) and then execute "git pull --rebase origin master". What exactly is doing in this way?

Comment: The rebase is unlikely to produce the expected results.  What is needed here, since the tree is known to be in the goal state, is more of a "reparenting"; but rather than go through the hoops to do that with `filter-branch`, you can just prepare a new commit for master using a procedure like the one in my answer.

Comment: @AndreaNobili A push is actually to merge your local branch to the remote target branch in the remote repo. If the head of the remote target branch is an ancestor of the head of the local branch, then the push will be a fast-forward merge. If not, the 2 branches are diverged. Suppose the local branch is a-b-c-d, and the target is a-b-c-e. e is not an ancestor of d. By `git pull --rebase`, the local will be a-b-c-e-d'. Now e is an ancestor of d'. The push will be a fast-forward push. Fast-forward merge and true merge are explained in `git merge --help`.

Comment: This last comment ("...push is actually to merge...") is incorrect.  A push *cannot* do a merge; it either advances the remote ref like a fast-forward, or it moves it in a way that disrupts normal usage of the repo. (Which is why by default git rejects the ones that aren't "fast-forward like".)  And while a rebase *would* fix the commit topology, it also will likely cause changes to be mis-applied *because OP has said the changes from the other guy's master commit are unwanted*

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Thanks. But how is OP able or allowed to decide he does not want the changes from the other guy if it is a team-work repo? By rebase or merge, the tree will be the same although the commit graph will not.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I read the manual of `git push` again. I find "push is actually to merge" is partially right. I thought a non-fast-forward push would be allowed by configuration. The misunderstanding comes from the behavior of Gerrit. As the manual says, pull or rebase can solve the rejection.

Comment: @ElpieKay - *"...how is OP able or allowed to decide he does not want the changes...?"*  By reverting the changes he doesn't want.  Many procedures are possible; I've outlined one in my answer. Whether reverting a teammate's work is a good idea, is another matter (and is between OP and his teammate). *"...I find 'push is actually to merge' is partially right..."*  Then you find incorrectly.  Sorry, but these squishy almost-true statements serve nothing but to confuse people who are trying to understand git.  Merging is done locally.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the commit(s) exist on `detached HEAD` should be exist as commit(s) on your local `master` branch. So you need to migrate the changes from `detached HEAD` to your local `master` branch, then pull change from remote `master` branch in order to update local master branch, finally you can push your local `master` branch to bitbucket. Details as below:

```
#If you are still detached HEAD status
git checkout -b temp
git checkout master
git merge temp
git pull origin master -X ours #To keep the conflict files as local version, or you can use git pull origin master --rebase
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

In your explanation of what you did that led up to the error, something's either missing or unclear. You're in a detached HEAD state, which normally would mean you did a `checkout` of something other than a branch name.  That's fine, but it would be an important detail (and knowing what exactly you did and why may influence the recovery steps).

If you really *didn't* do a checkout, then something else happened that changed your `HEAD` value in an unexpected way.  When you restored your project files, did the backup include (some or all of) the `.git` directory?  (Manipulating the `.git` directory other than via git commands is risky business.)

Well, anyway, the first error tells us you're in detached head state.  The second error tells us that your detached HEAD has diverged from master.  In other words in your local repo you have

```
X --- X --- X --- A <--(origin/master)
             \
              B <--()
                    ^HEAD
```

or something similar.  Now, "push to master" means "make `origin/master` point here".  By default git resists making `origin/master` point to `B`, because then `A` is no longer reachable from `origin/master` whereas it was before.  This is an effective upstream rebase for all other users of the repository (see "recovering from upstream rebase" in the `git rebase` docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

This safety feature can be overridden, but I recommend against it; such a decision should be made deliberately by the team, and it seems rather like you've accidentally found yourself in this position.

Instead you should probably aim for a result like

```
X --- X --- X --- A --- B' <--(origin/master)
```

and if `B'` happens to revert all of the changes from `A`, that's between you and your coworkers.  So how to get there from here?

Well, assuming you've verified that your working tree (the project directory *excluding the `.git/` directory*) looks the way you want it, you can just carry that over onto master.

```
git reset --mixed master
```

will move your HEAD and the index state to master, but keep your work tree as is.

```
git add .
```

will update the index to match your work tree.  (You *could* use a `soft` reset instead of a `mixed` reset followed by an `add`, if you've confirmed that the index matches your work tree - which it probably should, but I'd want to make sure...)

```
git commit
git branch -f master
```

Now you should be able to push, unless `origin/master` has picked up still more commits in the interim.